# AngularJS $location.search() not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It's the first time I'm trying to use the $location service in AngularJS in order to check for query string arguments. I've been reading the docs and trying to play a bit with it in Plunkr to see how to use it, but so far I've failed to get it to retrieve any parameters from the query string.

I've been testing it using this plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/RIFdWa5ay2gmRa6Zw4gm?p=info

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
  .config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); 
  });

angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $location){
    $scope.name = "Andrei";
    $scope.url = $location.host();
    $scope.path = $location.path();
    $scope._params = $location.search();
  });
```

I've read that setting html5Mode(true) on the $locationProvider is required in order to get the $location service to work as "expected" - which I've done, but when setting this nothing works anymore in my plunk (you can set it to false and you'll see the binding are qorking again properly).

Am I missing something regarding the $location service?

Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Your Plunker isn't working.. for Angular 1.3 you need to add a base-tag in your HTML .. and after that your plunker is inside an iframe without query params (as you can see the path differs from the current URL path)

I'm using $location.search() myself for getting url params and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AngualarJS 1.3 `$location` in HTML5 mode requires a `<base>` tag to be present so that it knows the path that all of the links are relative to.  You can add `<base href="/" />` to get it working again.

http://plnkr.co/edit/j9rd1PajNLQVJ8r4c8BZ?p=preview

Comment: thank you for your comment! I've missed the base part of the AngularJS documentation. Indeed, once that is added to the index.html the code works again, but I still don't see the query string using the search() getter. Shouldn't in the above scenario (url) search() getter return {"p": "info" } ?

Comment: The URL for the iframe that the code run in is actually `"http://run.plnkr.co/b5QdYqBeapjRDHkk/"`, no query string.  The 'edit' url is for the page/plnkr app.

Comment: did a standalone test on my machine and got it working just as I wanted in the first place. Thanks a lot for your assistance!

Comment: @monstro It still works fine for me. Note that old versions IE does not support HTML5 mode and thus will not work.